# My JQueryAutocomplete won' work in asp net webForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

i get a little probleme that my JQuery doesn't show me a list of Autocomplete

i get a Form that show for the Client a the contrat that he have just by passing like the First Number of Contrat or middle

My JQuery

```
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            SearchText();  
        });  
        function SearchText() {  
            $("#txtEmpName").autocomplete({  
                source: function(request, response) {  
                    $.ajax({  
                        type: "POST",  
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetEmployeeName",  
                        data: "{'empName':'" + document.getElementById('txtEmpName').value + "'}",  
                        dataType: "json",  
                        success: function(data) {  
                            response(data.d);  
                        },  
                        error: function(result) {  
                            alert("No Match");  
                        }  
                    });  
                }  
            });  
        }  
    </script>
```

My Asp net

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<string> GetEmp(string empdetails)
        {
            string id_client = HttpContext.Current.Session["id_client"].ToString();
            List<string> emp = new List<string>();
            string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            string sqlquery = string.Format("select Num_contrat from [dbo].[Contrat] where Num_contrat LIKE '%'"+empdetails+"'%' and ClientNum_Client= '" + id_client + "' ", empdetails);
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while(sdr.Read())
            {
                emp.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
            }
            con.Close();
            return emp;


        }
```

AspNet

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Pas de Contrat" class="btn btn-dark mb-2 btn-sm" OnClientClick="javascript:return ShowHideDivOnButtonClick();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if `txtEmpName` is a asp.net webform control than at runtime this will get renamed to a unique name. The good thing is you can get that name by doing `<% txtEmpName.ClientID %>`

Change your code so the field references as those and all should work.

Comment: Show the page layout for the autocomplete control please.as you've changed please.